# Not able to add "/" in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Create a function based on the input and output. Look at [the examples](https://edabit.com/challenge/EoS5M5Smi8NPtzCWE), there is a pattern.

My code:

```
def secret(a):
b=a[:-2]
a_list=list(a)
last_number=int(a_list[-1])
Final_recurr=last_number+last_number
d="{} ".format(b)*Final_recurr
j=d.split()
for i,k in enumerate(j):
    if int(i)%2!=0:
        m="{}".format("</" + b+ ">")*Final_recurr
        return m
        
    if int(i)%2==0:
        m="{}".format("<" + b+ ">")*Final_recurr
        return m
```

I am not able to put `/` in every second iteration. Please tell me the mistake in current code and short version of this.

Comment: right, this is obviously a challenge that I'm not going to solve for you, but it should be three lines: 1: function definition; 2: split the argument into the bits before and after *; 3: combine the required string and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` or `str.partition` to split the string into separate parts:

```
>>> "div*2".partition("*")
('div', '*', '2')
>>> tag_name, _, mult = "div*2".partition("*")
>>> tag_name
'div'
>>> mult
'2'
```

Use string formatting to insert `tag_name` into a template:

```
>>> "<{}></{}>".format(tag_name, tag_name)
'<div></div>'
```

"multiply" the formatted string with `int(mult)`:

```
>>> "<{}></{}>".format(tag_name, tag_name) * int(mult)
'<div></div><div></div>'
>>>
```

Comment: it is possible to avoid repeating `tag_name` by naming the placeholders in format string: `'<{tag}></{tag}>'.format(tag=tag_name)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that can help you, try it out:

```
s = 'div*2'
>>> def secret(s):
    tag, n = s.split('*')      # parse it into two parts
    ans = f'<{tag}></{tag}>'   # get complementary part
    return ans * int(n)        # final result 

>>> secret(s)
'<div></div><div></div>'
>>> secret('p*1')
'<p></p>'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should familiarize more with programming basics before trying to solve challenges.

In this case, you have to understand that a `return` statement inside a function just exits the function even if it is in a loop.
Thus, at the first iteration of your `for i, k in enumerate(j):` loop, the code passes in the second condition and exits the function when it reaches the `return` statement.
So there is never a second loop and your loop is just inoperant.

Just fixing this problem won't be sufficient to get a working solution. I would advice to clarify in your head the steps needed to achieve what your want and even write them in the form of comments in an empty function (you could take steps suggested by @Qwerty in comment):

```py
def secret(expression):
    # split the argument into the bits before and after *
    # combine the required string
    # return the resulting string
```

Then try to address each comment, one at a time. Other responses should help you a lot in doing this.

---

Here are some links to the documentation of functions and concepts that could help you:

- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html?highlight=unpacking#expression-lists)